# What does yarn --prefer-offline do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, yarnpkg

I assume when I install npm package say react for the first time with

```
yarn add react
```

this will save react file in local cache. I found `.yarn-cache` to contain many files. I assume it is yarn local cache folder so that when I install react again in the future, it will be installed from local cache, no??

If I need to install react again in the future, should I simply write this:

```
yarn add react
```

or this:

```
yarn add react --prefer-offline
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

My understanding is that by default, yarn will always try to download the package from the internet when you install/restore it, and will also store that in the cache, which means that in the future if you try to install/restore and don't have an internet connection, it can fall back on the cache and install from there if necessary. By specifying `--prefer-offline`, you are reversing this behaviour so that it will check the cache first, and only try to download the package from the internet if it cannot find it in the cache. This can make your install/restores significantly quicker, and will allow you perform repeatable builds, but you may not get the latest versions available (e.g. if you're using version specs like ~1.2.3). There is also an `--offline` option, which will throw an error if it can't find a package in your local cache (i.e. it won't ever try to download from the internet).

More info at https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/

Comment: > but you may not get the latest versions available (e.g. if you're using version specs like ~1.2.3)

Wouldn't the yarn.lock file specify the exact version you need in that case?

Comment: If a lockfile is present, then yes it should

Answer (score 9):

In order to use `--prefer-offline` you first have to setup your offline package repo.

Let's setup our cache in a hidden dir in the home folder:

```
yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror ./.npm-offline
```

Also set a config to have yarn clean the dowloaded tarballs:

```
yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true
```

Now, whenever you run `yarn install` in some project, it will cache the modules in this directory, available for you to then fetch using `yarn --prefer-offline`.

When you want to later, perhaps in a new project, install from the cache you will need to specify the desired module version as it doesn't have a concept of `latest`. Easiest is to simply try to add:

```
yarn add moment
```

On my machine this prints:

```
error Couldn't find any versions for "moment" that matches "latest" in our cache. 
Possible versions: "2.1.0, 2.13.0, 2.17.0, 2.17.1, 2.18.1, 2.19.1, 2.19.2, 2.19.3, 2.8.4" 
// Note that above is not in semver order...
```

I can then install latest offline with:

```
yarn add moment@2.19.3
```

The Yarn blog [post](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/) mentioned by @adrian elaborates on how to a per project cache and how to commit that for your team if desired. I myself use just one cache for in order to be ideally able to bootstrap new projects while offline.

Comment: Is this --prefer-offline command supposed to apply default behavior to the "yarn add" process? I'm trying to create an angular project with yarn as the package manager, using "ng new myproject". This needs to be done with packages already downloaded to cache (as our organization requires these resources to be locked for security reasons). Since the angular-cli doesn't appear to be telling yarn to use the "--offline" flag, the cache-first requirement doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: It doesn't appear that yarn accepts `offline` or `prefer-offline` in its config so that option is out. Additionally `ng` only accepts `npm`, `yarn` or `cpnm` as in its `ng set --global packageManager=*` command. So my approach would be to 1) not have `cpnm` installed and 2) create a bash script in your path called `cpnm` that calls yarn with the `--prefer-offline` flag set. Then set `cpnm` as the default package manager for `ng`

Comment: @cyberwombat `.yarnrc` can accept default parameters for CLI args https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6398#issuecomment-499343824. just add `--install.prefer-offline true` to `yarn.rc`

Answer (score 3):

[A quite popular guy](https://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/) here at S.O. said:

> "Read the Source, Luke!"

And here is [the source](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/v0.24.2/src/cli/index.js#L36) of `yarn` CLI's `--prefer-offline` flag:

```
commander.option('--prefer-offline', 'use network only if dependencies are not available in local cache');
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Not too sure how this is an answer to OP. This isn't the actual source code run when this flag is passed to `yarn install`; it's just the output given for this flag when running `yarn install --help`. I'll give the OP the benefit of the doubt that they've read this help, otherwise how else would they know the flag itself exists?

Comment: Just adding to Andrew's comment: The feeling is that Yarn is pretty good at using the locally installed files, so why does this parameter exist?

Comment: I did a network drive, I kept the cache here, I replaced the github action cache that use a downloaded tarball, same speed using `--prefer-offline`