# Does yarn `--prefer-offline` by default

Tags: yarnpkg

`yarn` has a `--prefer-offline` flag

- Does it pull from the cache by default or is that flag needed?
- What is the purpose of the local package cache if the flag is not used?

Answer (score 0):

The flag changes behaviour.

If not set the default behaviour seems to be for `yarn` always to prefer to download if possible, using the cache only if offline.

Comment: So what is the point of the local cache if it doesn't use it?

Comment: @KirkStrobeck perhaps this answer can clarify: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44947023/3136861

Comment: As in my real experiments, using --prefer-offline flag make no difference when running `yarn` in github action. Which is really confusing.