# How to verify that yarn is really using the cache folder?

Tags: yarnpkg

I am using docker to install dependencies for one nextjs project.
Every time I run this custom CI it takes forever, although I might have installed the `yarn install` 3 minutes ago. The machine has persistent storage, I am building the packages from my local machine.

How can I verify that the cache is used or not?

My command is:

```
docker container run --rm --entrypoint='' -u root \
                  --platform linux/amd64 \
                  -v .:/usr/src/app \
                  -v ~/yarn-cache:/yarn-cache \
                  -w /usr/src/app \
                  node:16.4.0 /bin/bash -c 'YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/yarn-cache yarn install'
```

Please take note I am attaching the volume ~/yarn-cache to docker container /yarn-cache
then before running yarn install am specifying the cache folder as documented in yarn with the env varialbe

```
YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/yarn-cache
```

The folder ~/yarn-cache exists already in host machine and is never used or filled with data...

So from my understanding `yarn` that `runs inside docker container` is not using the cache folder that I specify with `YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/yarn-cache` before the command itself `yarn install`

Comment: Did you try with [`--prefer-offline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709240/what-does-yarn-prefer-offline-do)?